# How to get the rows without duplicate cells in result set

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the row with unique values :
Ex: In first-row name1 contain "AA" we have to compare the "AA" with all cells in the table if it matches we have to remove the entire row.

Below i/p result.

```
   declare @tbl table (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Name1 varchar(100),Name2 
   varchar(100),Name3 varchar(100)) 
   insert into @tbl 
   select 'AA' ,'AB','AC'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'BA','BB','AA'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'CA','CB','CC'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'DA','DB','DD'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'EA','AB','EC'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'CC','FB','FC' 
   SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Input: don't consider id column.

```
ID  Name1   Name2   Name3
1     AA       AB      AC
2     BA       BB      AA
3     CA       CB      CC
4     DA       DB      DD
5     EA       AB      EC
6     CC       FB      FC
```

expected o/p result:

```
ID  Name1   Name2   Name3
4     DA      DB      DD


declare @tbl table (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Name1 varchar(100),Name2 varchar(100),Name3 varchar(100)) 
insert into @tbl 
select 'AA' ,'AB','AC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BA','BB','AA'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CA','CB','CC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DA','DB','DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EA','AB','EC'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CC','FB','FC' 
SELECT * FROM @tbl a join @tbl b on a.name1<>b.name2 and a.name1<>b.name3 and a.Name2<>b.name3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below returns your desired results. If it can't join a row's Name1, Name2 or Name3 to Name1, Name2 or Name3 values in any other row then the values must be unique.

```sql
declare @tbl table (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name1 varchar(100),
    Name2 varchar(100),
    Name3 varchar(100)
);

insert into @tbl values
    ('AA', 'AB', 'AC'),
    ('BA', 'BB', 'AA'),
    ('CA', 'CB', 'CC'),
    ('DA', 'DB', 'DD'),
    ('EA', 'AB', 'EC'),
    ('CC', 'FB', 'FC');

select T1.*
from @tbl T1
left join @tbl T2 on T2.ID != T1.ID and (
    (T1.Name1 in (T2.Name1, T2.Name2, T2.Name3))
    or (T1.Name2 in (T2.Name1, T2.Name2, T2.Name3))
    or (T1.Name3 in (T2.Name1, T2.Name2, T2.Name3))
    )
where T2.ID is null;
```

=== edit ===

To ignore duplicate values anywhere at all in the table, even if they're on the same row, try this version instead...

```sql
declare @tbl table (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name1 varchar(100),
    Name2 varchar(100),
    Name3 varchar(100)
);

insert into @tbl values
    ('AA', 'AB', 'AC'),
    ('BA', 'BB', 'AA'),
    ('CA', 'CB', 'CC'),
    ('DA', 'DB', 'DD'),
    ('EA', 'AB', 'EC'),
    ('CC', 'FB', 'FC');

;with UniqueValues as (
    select Value
    from (
        select Value=Name1 from @tbl
        union all
        select Value=Name2 from @tbl
        union all
        select Value=Name3 from @tbl
    ) D
    group by Value
    having count(1)=1
)
select T1.*
from @Tbl T1
join UniqueValues U1 on U1.Value=T1.Name1
join UniqueValues U2 on U2.Value=T1.Name2
join UniqueValues U3 on U3.Value=T1.Name3;
```

Comment: It not validating on same row.